# How can I take multiple photos using camera and save all of it to the application's directory

Tags: flutter

I tried to take 8 photos in 1 button press with:

```
String timestamp() => DateTime.now().microsecond.toString();

final Directory extDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final String dirPath = '${extDir.path}/Pictures/CameraApp';
await Directory(dirPath).create(recursive: true);
final String filePath = '$dirPath/${timestamp()}.jpg';

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
  await controller.takePicture(filePath);
}
```

When i checked the app directory, it seems that the app only save the last taken photo. I need to get all that 8 photos into the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calculating a single string for your filepath, then overwriting it 8 times, rather than calling your timestamp() function for every picture which would give you 8 unique file names.